# How to create a java Web application in netbeans with Java EE 7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, java-7, java-ee-7

I downloaded the JDK 7 and I Installed it, even if I go to `Tools/java platforms` it is in there

[image]

but when I want to create a new app, in the secction of Server and Settings in "Java EE Version" I only have Java EE 5 available to set.

[image]

What can I do to be able to set Java EE7 as a version?

Comment: Just install a new Java SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versions of Java EE available depend on the version of the server. Tomcat6 only supports Java EE 5. To use Java EE 7, either select a different server in the drop down list if one is already installed or click the `Add ...` button next to the server to add one that supports Java EE 7. Glassfish is probably the easiest option , it supports Java EE 7  and can be downloaded and installed from that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to upgrade Netbeans 8.0 which support Java EE 7.